# the user must match to the 3 fields

Tags: vb.net, authentication

```
Dim elem As String
elem = "Grade School"
Dim v As Integer
v = 0
Dim con As New SqlConnection("SERVER=ANINGDZTS-PC;DATABASE=AEVS;Trusted_Connection = yes;")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Voter WHERE Department, VotersID  = '" & elem & "''" & txt_PwordElem.Text & "'AND Voted ='" & v & "'", con)

con.Open()
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Try
    If (sdr.Read() = False) Then
        high()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("WELCOME!")
        elemBallot.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
Catch EX As Exception
    MsgBox(EX.Message)
End Try

End Sub
```

this code is not working, an error appear," An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to create your SQL query via concatenating strings, which is prone to errors, a much better way is to use parametrized query. Change your SqlCommand declaration to

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Voter WHERE Department = @Department AND VotersID = @VotersID AND Voted = @Voted", con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", elem)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VotersID", txt_PwordElem.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voted", v)
```

Bonus: Avoid SQL Injection

P.S. Please don't forget to close your Reader and Connection after the use.

P.P.S. If you simple need to make sure that specific row in table "tbl_Voter" exists or not based on your parameters (which is, judging by the code what you're doing) - using DataReader is overkill. Consider query like `SELECT 1 FROM tbl_Voter ...` and use of [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to check returned value for Nothing

Comment: @DayanaraDiazTorres Glad it worked for you :) Please check the answer as accepted if solution was helpful.